# Apache PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager throwing illegal state exception

Tags: java, connection-pooling, apache-httpclient-4.x

Here is how I use it -

```
private static final PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connPool;

static {

        connPool = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
        // Increase max total connection to 200
        connPool.setMaxTotal(200);//configurable through app.properties
        // Increase default max connection per route to 50
        connPool.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(20);//configurable through app.properties

}

CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                .setConnectionManager(connPool) .build();
```

ALso I have put a finally block around http GET -

```
finally {
            try {
                httpClient.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.error(e.getMessage());   
            }
        }
```

Here is my stacktrace -

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:169)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:217)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:157)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:194)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:85)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
    at com.A.B.C.CustomHttpClient.doGETAndValidate(CustomHttpClient.java:44)
    at com.A.B.C.SiteMonitorTask.monitorAndUpdateEndPoints(SiteMonitorTask.java:48)
    at com.A.B.C.SiteMonitorTask.run(SiteMonitorTask.java:37)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I am using Quartz to schedule a job of monitoring Http end points.. Here is my connection pool configuration

```
totalMaxHttpConn=200
maxHttpConnPerRoute=20
```

Maven dependency.. artifact version

```
httpclient 4.3.1
httpcore 4.3.1
```

**EDIT** - Well the problem got away by not closing CloseableHttpClient in the finally block.. Can anyone tell why is it behaving like that? **Why is connection pool shut down if i close a client?**

**Is the closeablehttpclient above is a handle to the pool rather than a single conn**

Comment: And where is the code where you are accessing the pool? My bet is the pool is closed by someone/something when you are accessing it.

Comment: Does the code above suffice?

Comment: Was searching for a suitable doc link to explain that. You should be releasing the connection and not close it. You're not actually closing a client. IOW, a client is the actual connection that you create to your HTTP URL.

Comment: there is no API like release connection for CloseableHttpClient

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management - may be this should help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This behavior is due to a bug in HC 4.3. It has already been fixed in HC 4.4a1. As of 4.4 `CloseableHttpClient#close` should automatically shut down the connection pool only if exclusively owned by the client

Comment: Do you happen to know the bug id?

Comment: No ticket was raised for the defect but i can give you the revision number if you like

Comment: As of now, fixed the issue by removing httpClient.close().. Did not test the rev number provided by oleg..

Comment: I'm using Jersey2.6 backed by `PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager`. Will it have the same issue?

Comment: This is not what I observed in version 4.5.

Multiple clients were registered, but the connection manager would be closed anyway.

setConnectionManagerShared() solved the issue

Answer (score 58):

In version 4.4 the method `setConnectionManagerShared(boolean)` was added to `HttpClientBuilder`.

If you set it to true the client won't close the connection manager.

```
HttpClients.custom()
            .setConnectionManager(Util.getConnectionManager()) // shared connection manager
            .setConnectionManagerShared(true)
```