# Java Connection Pool Shut Down

Tags: java, apache, http, post, elasticsearch

I am running Apache HTTP POST Request in Java and start getting the following error whenever I exceed ~ 1300 requests, I need to make a lot more requests ~40k what can I do to rectify the same?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Connection pool shut down
    at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
    at org.apache.http.pool.AbstractConnPool.lease(AbstractConnPool.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.requestConnection(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:251)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:175)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:107)
    at io.searchbox.client.http.JestHttpClient.execute(JestHttpClient.java:48)
    at code.niki.elasticSearchBase.Location.LocationAPI.writeBulkLocation(LocationAPI.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor28.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager throwing illegal state exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889925/apache-poolinghttpclientconnectionmanager-throwing-illegal-state-exception)

Answer (score 0):

It was definitely a bug caused by a `LoadBalancingPolicy` instance being shared across the two clusters.
Please refer to the link [here](https://github.com/datastax/python-driver/commit/f4168534dade15feedebd93bd1d47551e0594fc1).